# Are CPU and GPU embedded on the logic board?

Tags: macbook-pro, logicboard

I'm thinking about whether I should get my MacBook Pro 6,2 repaired. The repair would include replacing the logic board, so I'm wondering if the CPU and GPU are replaced as well?

Comment: Sorry for the bad news, but practically no laptops have socketed CPUs, graphics cards or other components. The sockets/connectors require use up too much of the precious internal volume. It's the same for most mobile devices, "all-in-ones," laptops, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see on the image below, the CPU (red border) and the GPU (orange and yellow border) are wave soldiered onto the logic board and they will be replaced together.

BUT, you should know this kind of replacements are extremely expensive. Prices goes up to $1,000 so in most cases it's better to buy a new Mac. It's not uncommon to find "older" refurbished Macs at similar prices to logic board replacements.

You Mac is almost 3 years old and if I were you, I wouldn't do the repair and just go for a new Mac.

[image]

Comment: Where do you know how old the computer is?

Comment: In his original question was the computername, MacBook Pro 6,2 which means a mid 2010 model!

Comment: When you edit a question, please try not alter its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the MacBook Pro [photos and replacement parts on the iFixIt](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Core+2+Duo+Models+A1226+and+A1260+Logic+Board+Replacement/681/1) suggest the Central Processing Unit (CPU) and Graphics Processing Unit (GPU) are embedded on the main logic board.

Answer (score -1):

Apple flat rate repair is $310.  Take your computer to the Apple Store.

I got my Macbook Pro 6,2 repaired, by taking it to the Apple Store.  The Apple Store offered me flat rate repair for $310.  They replaced my logic board 3 times and on the third time refunded their repair charge.  Authorized Service Provider  in Mexico had wanted $1,200 to replace the logic board or $250 to re-ball the BGA of the GPU.  He told me the re-balling might not work and sometimes works only for a few months.  So flat rate depot repair in the USA was the best option for me. Each logic board replacement took 5-7 days.

The flat rate repair is available in the USA, but not Mexico.  (There are only Apple resellers in Mexico.)  Start with an Apple Store genius.  I don't know about Norway.  Good luck!

Lots of people are having problems with the early 2011 Macbook Pro.  135 pages of discussion on it.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2768351?start=0&tstart=0